# FutureBuilder not called

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some trouble about FutureBuilder. I tried to call a FutureBuilder inside Inkwell `onTap`, but I dont know why its not working at all.

```
class ScheduleViewState extends State<ScheduleView> {
  late ScheduleService scheduleService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scheduleService = ScheduleService();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Daftar Dokter"),),
        body: _buildListView(widget.data, scheduleService)
    );
  }
}
```

This is where I put the Inkwell Widget

```
Widget _buildListView(List<Doctor> doctors, ScheduleService scheduleService) {
  return ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]),
      itemCount: doctors.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Doctor doctor = doctors[index];
        return InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            _buildDialog(scheduleService, doctor.doctorId);
          },
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
  );
}
```

And this is my FutureBuilder

```
Widget _buildDialog (ScheduleService scheduleService, int id) {
  return FutureBuilder<Schedule>(
      future: scheduleService.getSchedule("Monday", id),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print("Test");
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot);
          return Center(
            child: Text("Error"),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData){
          print(snapshot.data);
          return Text("test");
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Container(),
          );
        }
      });
}
```

The print command is not reached, so I assume that the entire FutureBuilder is not working. maybe I miss something? Please tell me if I miss something in the code. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't miss anything, you're just using `FutureBuilder` totally incorrectly. What are you trying to achieve with `_buildDialog`?

Comment: Ah, I tried to show an alert dialog that contain a data from the scheduleService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not displaying the dialog:

```
Future<void> _buildDialog(BuildContext context, ScheduleService scheduleService, int id) async {
  await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: FutureBuilder<Schedule>(
          future: scheduleService.getSchedule("Monday", id),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print("Test");

            if(snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot);
              return Center(child: Text("Error"));

            } else if (snapshot.hasData){
              print(snapshot.data);
              return Text("test");

            } else {
              return Center(child: Container());
            }
          }),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Call it passing the `ListView` context as first argument:

```dart
return ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]),
  itemCount: doctors.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    Doctor doctor = doctors[index];
    return InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        _buildDialog(context, scheduleService, doctor.doctorId);
      },
      child: Row(children: <Widget>[]),
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Don't you think you should make the `onTap` an asynchronous function?